# Expression Blend 4 accidently deleted App.xaml - now new problems with static main method

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I accidently deleted by App.xaml and App.xaml.cs files in my blend 4 project.

So I made a new one successfully - however now when I go to run the app it says :

ok done that thanks, now it says Program " does not have a static main method suitable for an entry point.

How do I make its main method - where should it exist , and what should it look like!?

Comment: Uh... Revert to last known-good commit?

Comment: @Marc, that's assuming the project is under source control... which is probably not the case if he's asking this question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in app.xaml add StartupUri to Main Window/Page etc.

```
<Application ...
 StartupUri="Menu.xaml"
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make its main method - where should it exist , and what should it look like!?

In a WPF application, you typically don't create the `Main` method yourself. It is generated based on App.xaml. You need to make sure that the build action for App.xaml is set to *ApplicationDefinition* and the custom tool is set to *MSBuild:Compile*, otherwise the `Main` method won't be generated (this is for VS, no Blend, but I assume Blend has something similar)